# Epsilon Delta definition of a Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

The derivative at a specific point $c$ is represented as a limit by:
$$ f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} $$

It's clear to me that the epsilon delta definition of a derivative at a point $c$ would be:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 ~\exists \delta > 0 \forall x: \\
0 < |x-c| < \delta \rightarrow |\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - L| < \epsilon
$$

What's unclear to me is how to formally represent the derivative as a function of $x$, rather than only at point $c$.  Basically, how would we represent this limit formally (the $\Delta x$ is the part tripping me up):

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do know the definition of limit, right? So, just apply it. We can argue that if the derivative at $x$ is $L$, then
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 ~\exists \delta > 0 \;\forall \Delta x: \\
0<|\Delta x| < \delta \implies \left|\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}-L\right| < \epsilon$$
Also, the derivative as a function, $f^\prime (x)$ is simply a function which takes a point in, and spits out the derivative of $f$ at that point. So, you can also define definition of a derivative at a point $c$ and collect all those derivatives under a function.

Comment: Ok thanks.. and delta x just represents a distance from whatever point we're considering

Comment: @bgcode yes, you can say that. Or you may also say that $\Delta x$ is just a (small) real number- in the context of $\mathbb R$, both of them are same, doesn't really matter!

Comment: This seems to me to be doubly defective: (a) The $\forall x$ is wrong, it should be $\forall\Delta x$; (b) The condition yields that $f'(x)=0$, You need to write a proper $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the phrase "$f$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative $L$"

Comment: @ancientmathematician corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out. I must have been daydreaming when I wrote that :|

Comment: Sayan: you may want to add $\forall \Delta x$ then?

Comment: @bgcode done $\;$

Comment: strictly speaking it should be $0<|\Delta x|<\delta$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo fine now?

Comment: Should be L(x), no? Otherwise  you're comparing a variable to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You may write the last formula as :

$$f'(c) = \lim_{\Delta x\to0} \frac{f(c + \Delta x) - f(c)}{c+\Delta x-c}$$

The last formula appears more intuitive when looking at $f'$ as a function and not at $f'(x)$, which is the value of the derivative at $x$. Indeed the limit of the variable does not depend on the point (i.e. we have $\Delta x \to 0$ and not $x \to c$).

Formally, if you had to write an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof of a formula for a derivative, for example if $f(x)=x^n$, then $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$, you have to prove it independently for any $x$. So you may start your proof by "let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then ...". But once this formula has been proven, then you can easily compute the derivative of any polynomial.

**Note**

I am unsure I have well spotted your misunderstanding so I gave a quite general answer. I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my misunderstanding was regarding $\Delta x$ and thinking it might change when we use epsilon-delta.  giving both of you upvotes

Comment: Glad to hear we have been useful then. ;)